# PCB Ethernet instability - CM4 Breakout Board

Tags: pcb-design, ethernet, interference, cm4

I am creating a breakout board for the Raspberry Pi CM4 which should support Gigabit Ethernet and POE. I embedded a magjack onto the breakout board.

I am struggling with the connection stability, however: the CM4 successfully connects and I can measure speeds of up to 1 Gbps both ways, with no packet loss, however after a minute or so the connection drops completely.

I can see console messages saying the eth0 interface keeps dropping and reconnecting for less than 1 second.

My guess is a hardware issue, but I don't know what could it be: either PCB trace design, wrong impedance, or potentially overheating.

In theory, my design matches the manufacturer's requirements for 50 Ω differential impedance.

I did notice the board getting very warm (I'm measuring approx 40 ºC), could that be causing issues?

Finally, when it comes to POE, how should the magjack be grounded? Using the Ethernet-side GND, not the CM4 side GND, right?

Here is the cut out of my Ethernet PCB traces.

[image: PCB design]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's is a CM4?

Comment: Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 - see https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/compute-module-4/

Comment: I'll be honest, I think your length matching is over the top (not that that would be a problem); IIRC, 10ns skew between pairs is acceptable (of course, lower is better), and that's like 1.5m length difference at 2/3 speed of light. You correct for maybe 10 mm of difference ;) I'd be more worried about the appropriateness of the AC ground connecting top layer trace there.

Comment: Thanks @MarcusMüller! Could the AC ground be causing issues to the stability of the Ethernet signal? (Bear in mind this is on a 4 layer PCB with two GND layers in between). Is it technically correct to be grounding the magjack to the AC ground, but to have the DC-side ground plane around the signal traces?

Comment: @nzapponi nah, I think it's unlikely to be the problem :)

Comment: Which magjack that is? Have you got schematics and part list? What does the single capacitor do, and the wire it has? Do you happen to have the PHY side ESD diodes and PHY side center taps grounded to the isolated Ethernet side? That can't work.

Comment: @Justme thanks for looking into it!! The Magjack is a TRP 2250504-1, the single capacitor was borrowed from the CM4IO datasheet (I assume it's for isolation?), see  C1 at https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/cm4io/cm4io-datasheet.pdf . Yes, the PHY side ESD diodes & the magjack shield are grounded to the isolated Ethernet side. Why is that a problem? Thanks again!!

Answer (score 4):

Ethernet should be an isolated interface. Which means the PHY side signals and cable side signals should not be referenced with each other as they are isolated with the transformer.
This isolation allows the MCU side and cable side to have multiple hundred volts between them.

But that design has ESD diodes on the PHY data lines, but the ESD diode ground is not connected to PHY ground, but to Ethernet cable side ground.

If there is more than the ESD diode clamping voltage between data lines and Ethernet ground, it will affect the data signals to PHY.

For example if the RPi module is on a floating supply but ESD diodes are clamping to Earth ground, it is a problem. Also it is a problem if RPi module ground is referenced to Earth ground and the Ethernet cable is connected to a floating supply. It might work if the RPi module and the other Ethernet device is also Earth referenced.

Without schematics and diagram of magjack internals, it is not sure what other problems there might are, but safe to say that based on the PCB diagram, the Ethernet interface does not match the reference schematics and is not properly implemented.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I'll test it out and get back with findings

Comment: does the decoupling capacitor on the center tap also need to be grounded to PHY ground? Whereas the shield needs to be grounded cable side, right? Thanks again

Comment: This design uses a Magjack, the ESD diodes are between the magnetics and Phy, these signals are referenced to signal ground, not to chassis or shield ground.